# SQLite page cache keeps growing -- performance drops

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite

We have an iOS app that suffers performance problems -- long transaction times.  Some of the transactions that are involved are large -- hundreds of updates, but when the problem occurs the duration of a given transaction increases by a factor of 20 or so (so it can go from 3 seconds to 60).  And, observing transaction times (both short and long ones), the time of a given type of transaction can be seen to grow slowly and steadily until some point where it suddenly leaps upward.  This all appears to be tied to the database size or the number of transactions that have ever been used on it.  (The problem persists after an app restart.)

By doing timed calls to `sqlite3_status` I've found that the "PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW" figure appears to grow as performance worsens, until the "leap", at which point it appears to be "pegged" around 2,351,392, varying maybe 10,000 above and below that number.

(Not much point in including any code here, since I wouldn't know which of maybe 50,000 lines to include, but I can include some more data if someone wishes.)

Here is the basic time data, to illustrate the problem:

```
Line 6003: 2013-01-17 17:05:57.296 [640f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bd7490> (operation count 50) for TestCase 31 was 0.007225
Line 6006: 2013-01-17 17:05:57.699 [640f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bdcc50> (operation count 100) for TestCase 31 was 0.012519
Line 6008: 2013-01-17 17:05:58.130 [640f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7be3ce0> (operation count 150) for TestCase 31 was 0.012854
Line 6011: 2013-01-17 17:05:58.614 [640f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bead70> (operation count 200) for TestCase 31 was 0.012298
Line 6013: 2013-01-17 17:05:59.117 [640f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bf1dd0> (operation count 250) for TestCase 31 was 0.008589
Line 10158: 2013-01-17 17:10:59.635 [6e6b] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b6a370> (operation count 50) for TestCase 20 was 0.019303
Line 10161: 2013-01-17 17:11:00.526 [6e6b] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b704a0> (operation count 100) for TestCase 20 was 0.090055
Line 10164: 2013-01-17 17:11:01.354 [6e6b] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7ea94b0> (operation count 150) for TestCase 20 was 0.014182
Line 13712: 2013-01-17 17:11:08.467 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e77090> (operation count 50) for TestCase 21 was 0.014494
Line 13714: 2013-01-17 17:11:09.368 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e7dae0> (operation count 100) for TestCase 21 was 0.016176
Line 16852: 2013-01-17 17:11:15.417 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e5da90> (operation count 50) for TestCase 22 was 0.016824
Line 16854: 2013-01-17 17:11:16.469 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e81e50> (operation count 100) for TestCase 22 was 0.018769
Line 18: 2013-01-17 17:11:24.845 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b14fa0> (operation count 50) for TestCase 13 was 0.025399
Line 21: 2013-01-17 17:11:26.447 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bd4cb0> (operation count 100) for TestCase 13 was 0.025167
Line 23: 2013-01-17 17:11:27.886 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e3acf0> (operation count 150) for TestCase 13 was 0.026859
Line 27: 2013-01-17 17:11:29.353 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7ee8920> (operation count 200) for TestCase 13 was 0.019391
Line 29: 2013-01-17 17:11:30.601 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7eef680> (operation count 250) for TestCase 13 was 0.019822
Line 5742: 2013-01-17 17:11:41.681 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x5730970> (operation count 50) for TestCase 23 was 0.081646
Line 5745: 2013-01-17 17:11:43.421 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b263f0> (operation count 100) for TestCase 23 was 0.021661
Line 5747: 2013-01-17 17:11:44.821 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7f86ff0> (operation count 150) for TestCase 23 was 0.028541
Line 5750: 2013-01-17 17:11:46.233 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b7fda0> (operation count 200) for TestCase 23 was 0.023087
Line 5752: 2013-01-17 17:11:47.696 [1b97] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e64400> (operation count 250) for TestCase 23 was 0.030041
Line 10685: 2013-01-17 17:12:04.873 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x84a0ec0> (operation count 50) for TestCase 24 was 0.030812
Line 10687: 2013-01-17 17:12:06.479 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x5728a80> (operation count 100) for TestCase 24 was 0.026640
Line 10690: 2013-01-17 17:12:08.147 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e5f130> (operation count 150) for TestCase 24 was 0.029734
Line 10692: 2013-01-17 17:12:09.807 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b0d280> (operation count 200) for TestCase 24 was 0.039982
Line 15692: 2013-01-17 17:12:20.456 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x83edb60> (operation count 50) for TestCase 25 was 0.044163
Line 15695: 2013-01-17 17:12:22.265 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b8d1c0> (operation count 100) for TestCase 25 was 0.036278
Line 15697: 2013-01-17 17:12:24.092 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e4fa90> (operation count 150) for TestCase 25 was 0.039441
Line 15700: 2013-01-17 17:12:25.957 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7f63ef0> (operation count 200) for TestCase 25 was 0.044993
Line 15702: 2013-01-17 17:12:27.844 [6473] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x84e9d00> (operation count 250) for TestCase 25 was 0.039544
Line 20761: 2013-01-17 17:12:36.498 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e7f600> (operation count 50) for TestCase 26 was 0.036249
Line 20763: 2013-01-17 17:12:39.247 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b30960> (operation count 100) for TestCase 26 was 0.058809
Line 20767: 2013-01-17 17:12:41.772 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7ea9a70> (operation count 150) for TestCase 26 was 0.048724
Line 20769: 2013-01-17 17:12:43.768 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b287b0> (operation count 200) for TestCase 26 was 0.040958
Line 20772: 2013-01-17 17:12:45.788 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7b64eb0> (operation count 250) for TestCase 26 was 0.040524
Line 17: 2013-01-17 17:12:58.002 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7f78130> (operation count 50) for TestCase 27 was 0.049245
Line 20: 2013-01-17 17:13:00.157 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7eacf20> (operation count 100) for TestCase 27 was 0.042884
Line 22: 2013-01-17 17:13:02.323 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x83e0de0> (operation count 150) for TestCase 27 was 0.043717
Line 25: 2013-01-17 17:13:04.483 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e2f690> (operation count 200) for TestCase 27 was 0.044739
Line 27: 2013-01-17 17:13:06.686 [9327] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7f6c7f0> (operation count 250) for TestCase 27 was 0.044045
Line 5109: 2013-01-17 17:13:33.149 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x8444de0> (operation count 50) for TestCase 28 was 0.054260
Line 5112: 2013-01-17 17:13:35.969 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7f6fd50> (operation count 100) for TestCase 28 was 0.065153
Line 5114: 2013-01-17 17:13:38.885 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7ee9b10> (operation count 150) for TestCase 28 was 0.046428
Line 5117: 2013-01-17 17:13:41.801 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7bc66a0> (operation count 200) for TestCase 28 was 0.057400
Line 5119: 2013-01-17 17:13:44.749 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7efadb0> (operation count 250) for TestCase 28 was 0.050737
Line 6553: 2013-01-17 17:13:52.572 [9613] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x85b71d0> (operation count 50) for TestCase 29 was 0.068941
Line 12883: 2013-01-17 17:51:57.413 [ff5f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x7e5d260> (operation count 50) for TestCase 6 was 0.217507
Line 12886: 2013-01-17 17:52:08.760 [ff5f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x84a4c60> (operation count 100) for TestCase 6 was 0.224743
Line 12888: 2013-01-17 17:52:20.051 [ff5f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x84f7110> (operation count 150) for TestCase 6 was 0.220262
Line 12891: 2013-01-17 17:52:31.397 [ff5f] [TestCase insertDependentRows:](1224) <PHI> Time to insert/update MyAppMarker <MyAppMarker: 0x8540ec0> (operation count 200) for TestCase 6 was 0.222045
```

So I guess the question is:  Does anyone know of a possible cause for this, or of a way to diagnose it further?

**Update:** Did some test using the Allocations option of the profiler.  It appears that a lot of DB inserts/updates are allocating (heap) space in the B-tree (which is in the PAGECACHE) and never freeing it.  I suppose this makes sense, but the amount of storage seems large.

Comment: How big is the DB file? How much data is accessed by your queries?

Comment: @CL. - The DB is apparently 7.6 MB.  I can't say for sure, but I believe small transactions represented above would be maybe 10 DB queries/updates.  There may be 200-400 of the small transactions in one large one.

Comment: Which specific query is taking so long? Do you have some schema/data that allows to reproduce this?

Comment: It's inserts/updates, mostly.  The DB is validly growing as the program progresses (downloading data), but the performance problem is way out of proportion to that growth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  It was *The Case of the Missing Indexes*.  When I ran the test long enough, and dumped the DB file size at intervals, it became clear that operation time was growing almost linearly with DB size.

Dug through the DB (I didn't set it up) and found several frequent `WHERE` clauses on large tables that didn't have corresponding indexes.  Added about 6 indexes and performance is now close to O(1).

I haven't had time yet to figure out to what extent the PAGECACHE stats may have changed, nor whether an apparent SQLite heap leak is gone.  I'll look at those a hair before calling it "good".

**Added:**  A minor cautionary tale -- it turned out that one of the indexes I added was already *supposed* to already be there.  Only it was coded as

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FileIdIndex ON FileMetaData (FileId)
```

when there was an earlier (in separate module, for "modularity")

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FileIdIndex ON Master (FileId)
```

So when you're creating an index name, it's best to put make the table name a part of the index name, as "FileIdToFileMetaDataIndex", to avoid name collisions.